# SSMS 2012 UDF Colours

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I want to know if its possible to change the colour of a User Defined Function in SSMS 2012.

It Currently looks like this:

[image]

So the function blends in with all the other fields, whereas the built in functions stand out:

[image]

Is this possible? Ive looked in the fonts and colors section but cant see anything seperated for UDFs

Answer (score 1):

Below are the ones given as default as per MS:

[image: colour code]

Below is one of the way you can check by giving it a try and see if it works and suits what you need:

To change font color, size, and style in the Editor

1. Click Options on the Tools menu.
2. Click Environment, and then click Fonts and Colors.
3. In the Show settings for list, select Text Editor.
4. Change the font, size, display item, foreground and background
   colors.

Also as stated per MS:

> There is only one font setting for the Editor and it affects all
>   editors in SQL Server Management Studio. You can change the color
>   based on the text type (such as comments and statements). Monospace
>   fonts appear in bold in the Font list, and you can apply bold settings
>   on a per-text-type basis. For example, you can format comments and
>   operators bold, and the other text types are unaffected.
>
> The settings for text color and font type are global for all text
>   element types, such as comments, strings, and so on.